# How to handle events processing time between services

Tags: events, microservices, publish-subscribe

Let's say we have two services A and B. B has a relation to A so it needs to know about the existing entities of A.

Service A publishes events every time an entity is created or updated. Service B subscribes to the events published by A and therefore knows about the entities existing in service A.

Problem: The client (UI or other micro services) creates a new entity 'a' and right away creates a new entity 'b' with a reference to 'a'. This is done without much delay so what happens if service B did not receive/handle the event from B before getting the create request with a reference to 'b'?

How should this be handled?

1. Service B must fail and the client should handle this and possibly do retry.
2. Service B accepts the entity and over time expect the relation to be fulfilled when the expected event is received. Service B provides a state for the entity that ensures it cannot be trusted before the relation have been verified.
3. It is poor design that the client can/has to do these two calls in the same transaction. The design should be different. How?
4. Other ways?

I know that event platforms like Kafka ensures very fast event transmittance but there will always be a delay and since this is an asynchronous process there will be kind of a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking about falls under the general category of bridging the gap between **Eventual Consistency** and good User Experience which is a well-documented challenge with a distributed architecture.  You have to choose between availability and consistency; typically you cannot have both.

Your example raises the question as to whether service boundaries are appropriate.  It's a common mistake to define microservice boundaries around Entities, but that's an anti-pattern.  Microservice boundaries should be consistent with **domain boundaries** related to the business use case, not how entities are modeled within those boundaries.  [Here's a good article](https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html) that discusses decomposition, but the TL;DR; is:

> Microservices should be verbs, not nouns.

So, for example, you could have a `CreateNewBusinessThing` microservice that handles this specific case.  But, for now, we'll assume you have good and valid reasons to have the services divided as they are.

The "right" solution in your case depends on the needs of the consuming service/application.  If the consumer is an application or User Interface of some sort, responsiveness is required and that becomes your overriding need.  If the consumer is another microservice, it may well be that it cares more about getting good "finalized" data rather than being responsive.

In either of those cases, one good option is a **facade** (aka gateway) service that lives between your client and the highly-dependent services.  This service can receive and persist the request, then respond however you'd like.  It can give the consumer a `200 - OK` response with an endpoint to call back to check status of the request - very responsive.  Or, it could receive a URL to use as a webhook when the response is completed from both back-end services, so it could notify the client directly.  Or it could publish events of its own (it likely should).  Essentially, you can tailor the facade service to provide to as many consumers as needed in the way each consumer wants to talk.

There are other options too.  You can look into [Task-Based UI](http://balazblogspot.blogspot.com/2018/07/what-is-task-based-ui.html), the [Saga pattern](https://bravenewgeek.com/tag/eventual-consistency/), or even just [Faking It](https://10consulting.com/2017/10/06/dealing-with-eventual-consistency/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to leverage the flexibility of a broker and the confirmation of a synchronous call . Both of them can be achieved by this

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html